# Registrations is or registrations are?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

When announcing that people can register for an event, which is correct: "Registrations are open" or "Registration is open"? I opt for the latter every time, but I have come across "Registrations are open." Registration appears to be both uncountable and countable, and I've found arguments for both, but is there actually a right way to use it? Could this be a difference in UK and US English?

Comment: Hello, Irena. 'Google ngrams' are a basic resource, and while imperfect and open to misinterpretation, are often the best method easily available to judge currency of short strings. There are general English, 'American English', and 'British English' corpora (amongst others) results available

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely make use of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitely a difference in usage between British and American English. Both phrases occur in American English, though 'Registration is open' is much more common. In British English 'Registrations are open' doesn't appear. ([Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=registration%20is%20open%2Cregistrations%20are%20open&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3)).  Registration as the action of registering is uncountable, registration as an individual form or piece of paper is countable, so it does depend on the context.